# Implementing pure virtual functions (operator overrides)

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement operator overrides (for use in a set). I have a base class and a derived class:

```
// Base.h
class Base {
  public:
    virtual bool operator < (const Base&) const = 0;
}

// Derived.h
class Derived : Base {
  public:
    virtual bool operator < (const Derived&) const; 
 
  private:
    int num;
}

// Derived.cpp
bool Derived::operator < (const Derived& obj) const {
  return num < obj.num;
}
```

My initial approach threw an error: 'Base': cannot instantiate abstract class when Derived is being used in another file. Is there a way to write a pure virtual function in Base such that all its Derived classes are required to implement it?

This is because there seems to be some redundancy if the same function declaration had to be made in every Derived class (apart from its parameter).

Comment: " 'Base': cannot instantiate abstract class" You are creating `Base` object somewhere, please post a [mcve], there is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: I have instantiated Derived in a driver file - the error is as a result of that file.

`Derived d{3};` for example

Comment: You didn't overload the pure virtual function hence `Derived` is still abstract, it must have the exact same signature as the function from `Base`.

Comment: Yea, as @πάνταῥεῖ says, I missed that, add `override` specifier next time and compiler will warn you.

Comment: Hmm that's what I understood from other posts too. Is there a way to "force" Derived to implement the operator override then in Base?\

Comment: What you are trying to do is called [covariant function parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Covariant_method_parameter_type) and there is no such thing in C++.

Comment: The `operator<()` in `Derived` accepts a `const Derived &` as an argument, which is different from the `operator<()` in `Base` (which accepts a `const Base &`).   So `Derived::operator<()` hides `Base::operator<()`, it doesn't override it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-share m. thanks for this! I had no clue what to search for